# Clustering and Contours in a Scatter Plot

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, scatter-plot, contour

I have a scatter plot from a dataframe. As you can see in the attached plot there is clustering on particular color types in specific portions of the plot. Is there an easy way to do clustering on colormap values and then draw contours. i.e. say select values between 0 and 5 (for colormap) and draw contours.

Sample Code to draw attached plot on a df:

```
df.plot.scatter(x='length',
                  y='width',
                  c='species',
                  colormap='viridis')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clustering is an unsupervised procedure that is blind of the labels / responses. The labels in your case of problem are the clustered-groups, that you don't have. All the other information (width, lengths and **even the species/color**) shall be seen as features of your data that you can use for unsupervised clustering.

**Reason why you should not operate on plots:**
The plots / colormap is just a way for us humans to understand the data with our tiny brains. It is however not required for sophisticated algorithms - those can work directly on your data features (length, width, ...). Of course there are exceptions from the rule, e.g. displaying audio-data as 2d images and running Convolutional Neural Networks to use their image classification strength. But let's focus on your standard case at hand:

**You want to find clusters in the data, and therefore you should operate directly on the data**
Let's reproduce an example like yours (next time please provide it with code if possible):

```
X = np.linspace(1,100,1000)
Y = np.random.normal(50,10,1000) # 1 series with randomized data
T = np.random.randint(1,30,1000) # respective species
Y2 = np.random.normal(70,2,1000) # 1 clustered band as second series
T2 = np.random.randint(1,15,1000)# respective species for second series

# combine series
X = np.r_[X,X]
Y = np.r_[Y,Y2]
T = np.r_[T,T2]
data = np.column_stack((X,Y,T))
#shuffle data so ML algorithms cannot take advantage of the order
np.random.shuffle(data)
# let's scale and cluster on the scaled data as this is common procedure
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
s = StandardScaler()
data_s = s.fit_transform(data)
```

[image]

Let's cluster:

```
from sklearn import mixture
clf = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=2, covariance_type='full', random_state=1) 
pred = clf.fit_predict(data_s)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(15,8))
axes = axes.ravel()
axes[0].scatter(data[:,0],data[:,1], c=data[:,2], cmap="jet", vmin=1, vmax=30, alpha=0.7, s=3)
axes[1].scatter(data_s[:,0],data_s[:,1], c=pred, cmap="jet", alpha=0.7, s=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

With all the given information (width, length and color) the clustering algorithm did a decent job separating the band from the other data.
PS: Information about different clustering algorithms: [sklearn clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html)